# How do I Create one Magento Product with 40 different types of Fabrics to choose from?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, swatches

What would be the best way to configure one product (a handbag) where you can have 40 different types of fabrics to choose from?

If I do this with Configurable Swatches, the page load time would be terrible because of all the images, right?

If I use Custom Options with a drop down, where do i put all those images?

Please could anybody advise what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

40 different fabrics is a lot but in magento world probably best way to do this is using configurable product. You shouldn't be worried about page load time if you use optimal hardware/software setup (like full page cache, CDN for media, etc.)

Custom options will be a bad choice especially if you need to invoice each type of handbag individiually. And with custom options you won't have any chance to display the fabric choosen without custom modifications.

Comment: However, I don't see the option to add images to configurable products?

Comment: Can you please mention your magento version? Magento ver 1.9.x already provide this thing. You can display different Image as per selected fabrics from drowdown on product view page. Shortly called it **Swatches** Image.